# Transforing improper integral into normal integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I had some basic integral: 
$$
I=\int _0^2 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}
$$
I have subsituted $u=\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}$ and got that
$$
I=2[\arcsin(u)]_0^1=\pi
$$
At the beginning $I$ was improper integral and the function was undefined for both $0$ and $2$, but $\arcsin$ is defined in both $0$ and $1$, so I don't need to calculate any limits? The final value is correct, but I don't know whether I can transform an improper integral into normal integral in such way.

Comment: Isn't $\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ improper?  The integrand is unbounded near $x=1$.

Comment: @saulspatz ah yes, I didn't see that. But still, now I need a limit only in $x=1$ and not in $x=0$?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you've done.  I'm sure there are examples where you can convert an improper integral into a proper one, but I don't have one in mind.  Someone will probably supply one soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There always exists a substitution to turn an improper integral into a nonimproper integral for absolutely integrable singularities, which means that they weren't true singularities to begin with.

Take for example

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\:dx$$

and let $x = u^2 \implies dx = 2u du$

$$\int_0^1 \frac{2u}{u}\:du = \int_0^1 2\:du = 2$$

Comment: Is there a proof of the first statement you said Sir ?

Comment: @Orion Pax that is the definition of an absolutely integrable singularity, Optimus Prime